# Click button in IE with not tag name or ID in Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have this page that I need to click the Continue button on but in the code there is no tag or id to reference.  So it doesn't seem I can use getElementsByTagName() or getElementById.  At least I've tried but still no luck.

I've tried getElementsByClassName as well but keeps getting errors.  For this particular code, what would work to click this button?

```
<div class="button-right ng-scope" ng-if"vm.accepted">
  <button class="btn btn--primary" type="button" ng-click="vm.confirm()">Continue</button>
</div>
```

I've tried

```
$continue = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('button-right') | Select-Object -First 1
$continue = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('button') | Select-Object -First 1
$continue = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn--primary') | Select-Object -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured it out with:

```
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("button") | ForEach-Object { $_.Click() }
```